# Extend angular-cli ng build to ignore git repository?

Tags: git, heroku, build, angular, angular-cli

Using angular-cli and a custom express server, I deployed a basic Angular2 application to heroku.  Running ng build is great at compiling all the Angular files, as well as the files I've added to the src and public directories.  However, some files I've had to add manually, and they are removed when running ng build.

The biggest problem is the git repository I'm using in the dist folder for deployment.  It is removed/overwritten every time I run ng build.  So instead of pushing changes to heroku, I have to initialize a new repo and push a new application.

Can ng build be extended to ignore or add files in the dist directory?

Comment: Can you map your base repo and instruct heoku to use dist folder.

Comment: Do not add any files manually in dist. Files that needs to be part of dist should be configured in vendorNpmFiles array inside angular-cli-build.js file

Comment: You are doing something wrong with 3rd party integration. Can you describe how you are doing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like I was going about this the wrong way.  Short answer for my case is to use gulp to pipe files from the dist directory into a different directory for deployment and pipe server files too.  If anyone is interested, here is the full work flow:

**In Development**

All the server files go into the src directory generated by angular-cli.  I use a server directory for models, routes, etc., and an app.js file for an entry point into the application.  These files are going to be added to the dist directory when ng build is run from the command line.  So the app.js file will point to the index.html.  Here's a simple example:

```
// app.js

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

router.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Express server started on port ' + port);
});

module.exports = app;
```

You can run ng build or ng test from the command line, and this will add the server files to the dist directory.  To run the application, use node dist/app from the command line.

**In Production**

When building for production using ng build -production, the server files in the src directory *are not* moved in the dist directory.  So I used gulp to create a new directory, add the files from the dist directory and the server files from the src directory.  I'm not great at task runners, so here's the full code:

From the command line: `npm install --save-dev gulp del`
Add gulpfile.js to the application root directory.

```
// gulpfile.js

var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');

// destination for piped files
var deployment = 'heroku';

// remove old files from the deployment directory
gulp.task('clean', function() {
    del([ (deployment + '/**/*'), '!.git']);
});

//  grab the angular files
gulp.task('angularFiles', function() {
    return gulp.src('dist/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(deployment));
});

// grab the server files and package.json
gulp.task('packageFile', function() {
    return gulp.src('package.json')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(deployment));
});

gulp.task('serverFiles', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/server/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(deployment + '/server'));
});

gulp.task('appFile', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/app.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(deployment));
});

// make a single task for the npm script
gulp.task('buildProd', ['angularFiles','packageFile','serverFiles','appFile']);
```

In the package.json file, make a new script: `"build:heroku": "gulp clean && ng b -prod && gulp buildProd"`

This runs the gulp tasks and uses the angular ng b -prod command, which, builds for production.

Run the script in the application root directory in the command line with `npm run build:heroku`

The first time you run run the script, it will create the deployment directory (called heroku in my case), clean it, add the angular files, then add the server files and package.json.  One thing I do manually, as I'm not a task runner expert, is remove excess scripts from the heroku directory so it looks like this:

```
// heroku/package.json
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js",
}
```

Otherwise, heroku may try to run some of the other angular npm scripts during deployment.

Then I cd into the heroku directory and use git for deployment. From the command line:

```
git init // only for first deployment
git add -A
git commit -m 'ready for deployment'
heroku create // only for first deployment
    -or-
heroku git:remote -a <heroku app name> // only for first deployment
git push heroku master
```

For subsequent deployments, the npm script build:heroku won't delete the git repository.  Just run the script, adjust the package.json, and use git to push to heroku.

**Few other things**

1. Remember to add the deployment directory to the main application's .gitignore file.
2. I've found dropbox sometimes causes conflicts with ng build -production.  Pausing dropbox syncing fixes the problem.
3. angular-cli `ng build` or `ng build -production` rewrites the dist folder every time.  So after deployment, you have to rebuild the development environment.  I personally use ng test and leave it running in the terminal.